# Linux links with "ln" command

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems, ext4

I'm writing a shell script in bash where I'm making some links between files, but I'm not sure what kind of link to use (physical or symbolic). Doing some research, I've noticed that it's more common to use symbolic links instead of physical ones. My question is why to use symbolic links when they require an indirection (it creates an extra I-node to safe the information about the real I-node of the file) instead of using hard links that point directly to the file?

In other words:

Why

```
ln -s ...
```

instead of

```
ln -P ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason for symlinks is that a 'soft' symlink can cross filesystem boundaries. The file representing the symlink will contain a string that is the actual path of the file being pointed at. As long as the end-user representations of that path remain the same, the symlink will work. If you move the file at the end of the symlink, the symlink will now be stale (aka "dangling"), because the resource it pointed at no longer exists.

A hard (aka physical) symlink works at the inode layer. Since inodes are only unique within a single file system, you cannot hardlink ACROSS file systems. You could quite easily run into a duplicate inode situation if this were allowed. The benefit is that no matter where you move the target of a hardlink, the links pointing at the resource will "follow", because they're pointing at the inode itself, and don't care what the actual path/resource name is.

Answer (score 3):

Off the top of my head:

1. symbol links work across filesystems. If you don't want to keep track of what filesystem the source file and destination link are on, or if you sometimes move files across filesystems, it is less of a hassle to use symbolic links.
2. $*@&#*$& `emacs` backup files. When you edit, say `file.txt` and make a change to it in emacs, emacs renames the original file to `file.txt~` and saves your changes under the original file name. If there was a hard link to `file.txt`, it is now linked to `file.txt~`, which is probably not what you want. A symbolic link to `file.txt` will still point to the updated inode.

Comment: how dare you speak out against the church of Emacs! j/k but you can solve that particular issue with (setq backup-by-copying t) more info here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/4237/how-to-prevent-emacs-from-breaking-hard-links

Answer (score 0):

A hardlink can only work on the same filesystem, renames the inode.  A file can only be deleted  when the last link to its inode is gone. Hardlinks usually are for files instead of directories.

A symlink is an actual file containing a path to another file. Symlinks can work across file systems as well. They can point to different file types as well. A symlink can also point to either files or directories.

Answer (score 0):

- Hard links don't make sense across filesystems, since they're basically pointers to inodes on the local FS.  Symlinks don't care; since they're just names, they can live anywhere.
- If you look at the directory listing and see a symlink, you know it's to a particular other location.  Hard links, on the other hand, offer no such clue.  You might not know you were playing around in some important file til you `stat` both its names.

Comment: Actually, you can tell if a file's hard linked from its link count (column 2 i `ls -l`).

Comment: @GordonDavisson: That still doesn't tell you what the file's other name(s) might be.  Try `ls -l` with a symlink.  You'll not only know it's a link to another file, but *which* file it's a link to.